# How would I use a null terminator in a char array so when I use fgets for input, it does not make a new line without using string libraries?

Tags: c

I know I essentially need to replace the `"\n"` with a `"\0"`, but how would I access the array to incorporate this?  I can not use string.h library or any other libraries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    char buffer[32];
    char digits[3];

    printf("Enter name:");
    fgets(buffer,32,stdin);



    printf("Enter age:");
    fgets(digits,3,stdin);

    char *name;
    name = buffer;

    int *age;
    age = atoi(digits);

    happyBirthday(name,age);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;` (this must be a duplicate)

Comment: BTW, make sure no one over 100 runs your program.

Comment: This does not work... can not use strcspn()

Comment: I was told to use three digits max for some reason in the assignment lol.

Comment: `int *age` should be `int age`. You should have gotten warnings about your code.

Comment: `char digits[3]` only allows 2 digits plus the null terminator.

Comment: Gotcha, my bad I misunderstood something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236915/discussion-between-amcode96-and-barmar).

Comment: `string.h` is not a library. It is a header. This is not mere pedantry; it is a fundamental misconception.

Comment: Do you know how to loop over an array? And do you know how to compare two characters? If you can do both of those things, you can do this.

Comment: Related: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471) (Probably not a duplicate because OP has stated restrictions in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
while (buffer[i] != '\0')
{
    if (buffer[i] == '\n') buffer[i] = '\0';
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Or more succinctly using a for loop:  `for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) { if (buffer[i] == '\n') { buffer[i] =  '\0'; } }`  We could even use pointer arithmetic to take out the unnecessary `i` variable. Though `i`, if not locally scoped to the loop, could be useful for keeping track of the length of the resulting string.